# How loop infinite DOM ready? with $.getjson

Tags: jquery, getjson

i need when Dom is ready loop infinite for check getjson, how can ?
Or have another form to try?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "js/json/nameplaylist.json", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            $('#nameplaylist').append('<option>'+value.title+'</option>')
        });
    }).fail(function(){ // If the AJAX call encountered an error
        console.log('no load nameplaylist');
        });
}
```

Comment: does this nameplaylist.json return all the values or just the new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timeout, something like that:

```
$(callJSON);

function callJSON() {
    $.getJSON("js/json/nameplaylist.json", function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $('#nameplaylist').append('<option>' + value.title + '</option>')
        });
    }).fail(function () { // If the AJAX call encountered an error
        console.log('no load nameplaylist');
    }).always(function () {
        setTimeout(callJSON, 5000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` to do that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function load() {
        $.getJSON("js/json/nameplaylist.json", function (data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('#nameplaylist').append('<option>' + value.title + '</option>')
            });
        }).fail(function () { // If the AJAX call encountered an error
            console.log('no load nameplaylist');
        });
    }
    //load on dom ready
    load();
    //load every 5 seconds
    setInterval(load, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Its best form to try? im find optimize my code,to consume few resources

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the DOM on each is expensive you should make this optimization:

```
var opts = "";
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    opts += '<option>'+value.title+'</option>';
});
$('#nameplaylist').append(opts);
```

Other replies seem to have solved the loop problem.